# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0'

Tags: asp.net, dll, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

I don't know what I did, but I may have removed `System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0` from the GAC.  I have a Windows Portable Library that targets WinRT that was compiling and working fine, and now I get the following error every time I try and run it

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

how can I re-add `System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0`?  Every time I look for the .dll, I find the 2.0.0.0 version?

Comment: Can you tell me if C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll is missing?

Comment: I got all the way, BUT the last folder (second to last command) was v4.0_2.0.0.0_b03f5f7f11d50a3a, so, there is a 2 near the beginning, not a 4.

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Windows 8.  I'm trying to build a WinRT application

Comment: To repair, you will need to run System Restore to restore Windows binaries to an earlier version when it did work. To help me understand the cause of this, did you uninstall something recently that might have broken this?

Comment: @DavidKean - Yes, that did it!  I manually removed the DLL from the GAC and couldn't find it to add it back in.  If you post an answer I'll upvote it and accept it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To repair this on versions of Windows prior to Windows 8, go to Add or Remove Programs and do a repair install of the .NET Framework 4.5.

To pair this on versions Windows 8 or greater, you will need to run System Restore to restore Windows binaries to an earlier version when it did work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to delete, then re-add the reference from the project?

Comment: The only reference in the project is `.NET Portable Subset` and I can't delete it and re-add it.  The package is dynamically created

Answer (score 0):

Try folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0
and copy the dll into GAC using gacutil tool from folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

Comment: That's the v4.0 dll.  I need to add the v4.5 dll.  Portable Libraries are for WinRT

Comment: No don't do that. Files are under "Reference Assemblies" are not real assemblies, do not install them in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

If it was but now is not, is high likely that you changed something in your project, if i understand correctly you're creating a Portable Library (not a Windows Store one), if that's the case, probably you changed what plataforms you're targeting, open the Properties of the project and in Library->Target Frameworks click on Change, there, if you have everything selected or .NET Framework 4.0.3 is selected, then System.Net.Http is not allowed, to solve this, you need to quit some selections and enable the .NET Framework 4.5, as this the minimum version to use System.Net.Http.