# Web API - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am developing angular js with web api.

I have this cotroller: Controller/MasterController, and thiis in my WebApi Config:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I call this function from Global.asax, Application_Start event.

I call my web api from service.js like that:

```
var service = function ($http) {
    var _$http = $http;
    self = this;
    self.getMenuItems = function () {
        var promise = _$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'api/Master'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
        return promise;
    };
```

In debug mode, I saw that I reach this area.
I get this error in chrome console:
**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404"**

and this is what he was trying to get to: `http://localhost:12345/api/Master`

Also, I tried to get to the web api controller directly through the browser, and I couldn't find it.

Thank You

Comment: What does your MasterController look like? The following should work if you use  http://localhost:12345/api/Master                                 using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class MasterController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello world";
        }
    }
}

Comment: public class MasterController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<MenuItem> Get()
        {
            //SOME FUNCTION
        }
   }

Comment: I tried what you proposed, didn't work

Comment: I would bet this is a server-side configuration problem. What I would do is create a simple page with jQuery, then call the server using `$.ajax()` from Firebug; tweak the configuration and repeat until your call succeeds. Also: have you tried a `Get(int id)` method signature? (or `int?` since it is optional - I do not know C# well enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some new directions, I received new error details.
The final error  I received + its solution you can find 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612920/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-4-0-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure your API is working try the following:

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

MasterController:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class MasterController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello world";
        }
   }
}
```

Calling http:// localhost:[SomePort]/api/Master in your browser should result in this:
    "Hello world"

The configurations above are all standard when creating a new WebApi.